# How to copy IterationPath, or value of IterationPath field on transition of WorkItem

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, workitem

In TFS, I need to be able to copy the value of the iteration path to another field to store. This is for historical purposes (so the user doesn't have to look through hundreds of changes in the change log.)

I realize I cannot create a field of type "TreePath". But since this is just for display, a read-only text editor will be fine.

Is there a way to copy the string value of the System.IterationPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's impossible. TFS restricts customization of system fields.

Most rules are disabled on the special system fields like `System.AreaPath` and `System.IterationPath`.

Please see [System field rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=vsts#system-field-rules) for details:

> System fields have System.Name reference names, for example
>   System.Title and System.State. **TFS restricts customization of these
>   fields, except for these instances**:
>
> - **HELPTEXT** rule can be assigned to all fields.
> - **READONLY** rule can be assigned to the State and Reason fields.
> - Most rules can be assigned to the Title, Assigned To, Description or    Changed By System fields.